# Using file upload jquery plugin in jsp page with strut action class

Tags: jquery, file-upload, struts2

I know there are many jquery plugins available for file upload.But it just shows how can we added it in the jsp page.But i want to know that how we can deal with the files that are selected using these plugins in the backend.For example am using spring with struts2.So i want to send these files in my action class from my jsp and to store it in the server location.Any body know how can i do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`userImage` is the name of the `<file>` tag

```
 public class FileUploadAction extends ActionSupport{
        private File userImage;
        private String userImageContentType;
        private String userImageFileName;

        private HttpServletRequest servletRequest;

        public String execute() {
            try {
                String filePath = "yourPath";
                File fileToCreate = new File(filePath, this.userImageFileName);

                FileUtils.copyFile(this.userImage, fileToCreate);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                addActionError(e.getMessage());

                return INPUT;
            }
            return SUCCESS;
        }

    }
```

From [this tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/struts-2-file-upload-save-tutorial-with-example/)

[This tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-upload-multiple-files-example/) explains multiple file upload usinf List

Comment: am extending crudActionSupport.Can i use the above method in my action class